# how to deal newsletter pop up when cookie or javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

am saving a cookie when ever user clicks on the **cross** button on newsletter
and same newsletter is not visible to the user until new newsletter is created.

```
 $('#wd1_nlpopup_close').on('click', function(e){
    $.cookie('wd1_nlpopup', 'closed', { expires: wd1_nlpopup_expires, path: '/' });
    $('#wd1_nlpopup,#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').fadeOut(200);
   this.preventDefault();
});

if($.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'closed' ){
    setTimeout(wd1_open_nlpopup, wd1_nlpopup_delay);
}
```

But the problem is this does not work even if the cookie or javascript is disabled and anyone suggest another way to overcome this problem.
**Without using SESSION**
Thanks

Comment: If you have no access to javascript, then you can't use the following: cookies, localstorage, sessionstorage, ajax functionality, etc. This means that the server needs to dictate when the request should be fulfilled.

Comment: so i will have to use database?

Comment: If Javascript is turned off you could access by using `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']` in PHP. And if you needed to set a cookie you could use the `setCookie()` method in PHP.

Comment: cookies are disabled too sometime i need universal solution irrespective of browser properties

Comment: Hmmm, you could use PHP Sessions, but the session id would be passed through the url rather than a cookie (which is less secure). Otherwise, you would have to use a database

Comment: in dataBase what should i save IP of the user?